# How to use Kibana query in Rest API

Tags: rest, elasticsearch

How to use Kibana query in Rest API.

My Query.

```
GET _search?&filter_path=hits.hits._source
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {"Status": "New"}
        },
        {
          "match": {"Locked": "False"}
        },
        {
         "range" : {
            "Date" : {
                "gte" : "now-1w/d",
                "lt" :  "now/d"
            }
        }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

i have  tried below Example   .

```
http://localhost:9200/_search?&filter_path=hits.hits._source%20{%20%22query%22:%20{%20%22bool%22:%20{%20%22must%22:%20[%20{%20%22match%22:%20{%22Status%22:%20%22New%22}%20},%20{%20%22match%22:%20{%22Locked%22:%20%22False%22}%20},%20{%20%22range%22%20:%20{%20%22Date%22%20:%20{%20%22gte%22%20:%20%22now-1w/d%22,%20%22lt%22%20:%20%22now/d%22%20}%20}%20}%20]%20}%20}%20}
```

But it will Return {}

please help me to done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [pass the JSON query in the HTTP query string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/common-options.html#_request_body_in_query_string) by passing the JSON query in the `source` query string parameter and specifying the `source_content_type=application/json` parameter.

Like this:

```
http://localhost:9200/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._source&source_content_type=application/json&source={"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"Status":"New"}},{"match":{"Locked":"False"}},{"range":{"Date":{"gte":"now-1w/d","lt":"now/d"}}}]}}}
```